# react-hook-form register function not working with generic extended type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-hook-form

I have 2 types - basic and extended:

```
type Basic = { a: string };
type Extended = Basic & { b: string };
```

I want to build generic view that will serve any type that extends my Basic type.

```
import React from 'react';
import { UseFormRegister, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

function GenericView<T extends Basic>({
  register,
}: {
  register: UseFormRegister<T>;
}) {
  return <input {...register('a')} />;
}

function MainView({ register }: { register: UseFormRegister<Extended> }) {
  return (
    <>
      <input {...register('b')} />
      <GenericView register={register} />
    </>
  );
}

export function Main() {
  const { register } = useForm<Extended>();
  return <MainView register={register} />;
}
```

When I'm trying to do this I'm getting typescript error in the GenericView:

```
Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Path<T>'.
```

adding example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-sound-44g986?file=/src/Main.tsx)